# filenotfounderror errno 2 no such file or directory

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to write a **discord bot** using discord.py.

In my bot I have command that get a image and **do something** after that zip it and send it.

All of my code is **OK** but I have a **error **in s**ending zip file**.

This is **error text:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Hesam\\Desktop\\New folder\\export_bdce64fb-079e-4b51-b6f0-8f798475aba6.zip'
```

This is function of my command:

```
@bot.command()
async def totem(ctx):
    try:
        url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
    except IndexError:
        print("Error: No attachments")
        await ctx.send("No attachments detected!")
    else:
        if url.startswith("https://cdn.discordapp.com"):
            r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                year = now.year
                month = now.month
                day = now.day
                hour = now.hour
                minute = now.minute
                second = now.second
                destination_path = os.path.join("exports", f"{year}", f"{month}", f"{day}", f"{hour}", f"{minute}", f"{second}")
                src = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "src")
                print(src)
                os.makedirs(destination_path, exist_ok=True)
                if os.path.exists(destination_path):
                    shutil.rmtree(destination_path)
                shutil.copytree(src, destination_path)
                file_name = os.path.join(destination_path, "assets", "minecraft", "textures", "item", "totem_of_undying.png")
                await ctx.send("making reasourse pack...")
                with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                        f.write(chunk)
                unicId = uuid.uuid4()
                zip_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"export_{unicId}.zip")
                print(zip_name)
                shutil.make_archive(zip_name, 'zip', destination_path)

                # file=discord.File(zip_name)
                await ctx.send(file=discord.File(zip_name))

            else:
                await ctx.send("Error: Failed to fetch the image!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid image link!")
```

Comment: Well, `FileNotFoundError` should be an error that is pretty straight forward: It's not existing in the given directory. Try to use `print` statements when it comes to determining the path and finding the file.

Comment: I checked all of them with debug and breakpoints and there are no problems. Even the file that the error says was not found exists with the exact same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive):

> base_name is the name of the file to create, including the path, minus any format-specific extension.

So do not include `.zip` in your archive name. Otherwise you are looking for `f"export_{unicId}.zip.zip"`. Do this instead:

```py
zip_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"export_{unicId}")
shutil.make_archive(zip_name, 'zip', destination_path)
```

Comment: Even further - `shutil.make_archive()` returns the full filepath of the created file, so get the return value and pass that to `discord.File()`

Comment: thank you nigh-anxiety ❤.
After your talk, I read the Shantil document and found out how to solve my problem.
Thanks a lot.